# Fibre internet speed too low on wired connection (20.04)

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, ethernet

### EDIT: Windows 10 has the same issue but when I turn off Ipv6, the speeds jumps to normal. However, turning it off on Ubuntu does not solve the same issue.

My Windows laptop goes up to 300 mbps, but when I connect my LAN cable to my Ubuntu 20.04, I get 80 mpbs max.

I've tried to disable IPv6 in my Wired connetion settings, but it doesn't work. It seems that somehow the speed is limitted. The cable is new and works fine with Windows.The router as well.

Here's ifconfig output:

```
    enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.100.6  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.100.255
        inet6 fe80::e6b9:7aff:fef1:ab  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e4:b9:7a:f1:00:ab  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 86497  bytes 120876882 (120.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 15133  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 22471  bytes 3146127 (3.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 984  bytes 113734 (113.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 984  bytes 113734 (113.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and

```
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:b9:7a:f1:00:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.6/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp2s0
       valid_lft 86159sec preferred_lft 86159sec
    inet6 fe80::e6b9:7aff:fef1:ab/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:2c:bc:76:2d:7f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp0s20f3
```

This is Dell Inspiron AiO.

Comment: How are you measuring your speed both on Windows and Ubuntu?  Are you using something like [Speedtest](https://www.speedtest.net/)?  Or basing it on transferring a particular file from a particular location?